# NetworkX / Pandas - can't output the degree of the nodes into a .txt file (error message)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I need to ouput the degree (as well other centrality metrics) of the nodes of a network into a .txt file. I was able to this in previous NetworkX / Pandas versions, but now I'm getting an error.

I'm using NetworkX ver. 2.1 and Pandas ver. 0.23.4:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    DEGREE = nx.degree(G),
    DEGREE_CENTRALITY = nx.degree_centrality(G),
    EIGENVECTOR = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G),
    KATZ = nx.katz_centrality_numpy(G),
    CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY = nx.closeness_centrality(G),
    BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY = nx.betweenness_centrality(G),
    CLUSTCOEF = nx.clustering(G),
)) 
#df.index += 1 
#df.to_csv('centrality-metrics.csv')
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/arthur/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 348, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/arthur/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 459, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/arthur/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7356, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/home/arthur/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7405, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to '
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Update: If I comment(#) the DEGREE line, the error won't happen. The output .txt would be similar to this (my original data is from a gene network):

```
GENE    BETWEENNESS CLOSENESS   CLUSTCOEF   DEGREE  DEGREE_CENTRALITY   EIGENVECTOR KATZ
A1BG    0.000142303010695361    0.318553702985653   0.0350877192982456  19  0.00115635080031647 7.26316435442522e-05    0.00556190357079266
A1CF    5.71271005407417e-05    0.33571705861921    0.375324675324675   56  0.00340819183251172 0.000225887126821305    -0.00251062164644857
A2M 0.000886299232394493    0.370534908894101   0.109265734265734   146 0.00888564299190554 0.00294316042120819 0.0163918804690203
A4GALT  7.38971769935498e-07    0.286369102602088   0   4   0.000243442273750837    1.35050378606586e-05    -0.000361261465931375
A4GNT   1.03038198147882e-05    0.297404430929626   0   15  0.000912908526565638    2.45985150882602e-05    0.00562955611859571
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with python 3.7.0, pandas 0.23.4, networkx 2.1

Comment: this likely has to do with the fact that in networkx v2.x `nx.degree(G)` returns what is called a 'DegreeView' object, which is similar to a dict.  What format do you need `DEGREE` to be in?

Comment: You are correct, the problem is in the DEGREE line. DEGREE should be in number (integers), just like in the example added to the original post

Comment: @joel nice catch on the v2.x networkx change in data type return from nx.degree method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay after reading the above comments ( @Joel ) and doing a [little research](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html), we can use `dict(G.degree)` instead of `nx.degree`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    DEGREE = dict(G.degree),
    DEGREE_CENTRALITY = nx.degree_centrality(G),
    EIGENVECTOR = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G),
    KATZ = nx.katz_centrality_numpy(G),
    CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY = nx.closeness_centrality(G),
    BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY = nx.betweenness_centrality(G),
    CLUSTCOEF = nx.clustering(G),
))
```

Output:

```
   DEGREE  DEGREE_CENTRALITY  EIGENVECTOR      KATZ  CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY  BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY  CLUSTCOEF
1       2                0.4     0.456984  0.408764              0.500000                     0.0   1.000000
2       2                0.4     0.456984  0.408764              0.500000                     0.0   1.000000
3       3                0.6     0.584217  0.448883              0.714286                     0.6   0.333333
4       3                0.6     0.417120  0.441314              0.714286                     0.7   0.000000
5       1                0.2     0.183076  0.367131              0.454545                     0.0   0.000000
6       1                0.2     0.183076  0.367131              0.454545                     0.0   0.000000
```